# How can measure how long it takes my script to run AND include that in an email it generates?

Tags: bash, shell-script, time

I have a simple bash script that runs a series of checks (`ping`, `nslookup`, etc) and then sends an email report with the output of that data.

I'd like the email to include information on how long it took the entire script to run.  Is there an easy way to collect that information?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at `bash` variable `SECONDS`:

> **SECONDS**: Each  time  this  parameter  is referenced, the number of seconds since shell invocation is returned.  If  a  value  is  assigned  to  SECONDS,  the  value returned  upon  subsequent  references  is  the  number  of seconds since the assignment plus the value assigned.

Thus you can simply print this variable at the end of the script. Alternatively, if your intention is to measure the time of only part of the program, then just set `SECONDS=0` at the beginning of the measured block of commands, and at the end just use value stored in this variable.

Comment: I never knew about `$SECONDS`; that's great! To add to this, you can convert seconds into hours:minutes:seconds with something like `date -d "1970-01-01 ${SECONDS} sec" +'%k:%M:%S'` (see `man date` for more formatting options).

Comment: I really like this approach but I'm still a little confused.  Let's say I run the same script a couple of seconds apart from one another.  If I set `SECONDS=0` on one script and the same thing on another script, will they interfere with one another?

Comment: Nevermind - I stumbled upon Tom's feedback in a Stack Overflow post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5153036/344780) which essentially subtracts the difference `START_TIME=$SECONDS; dosomething; ELAPSED_TIME=$(($SECONDS - $START_TIME))`.  This seems a bit more flexible for simultaneous use.

Answer (score 8):

Prefix your command with `/usr/bin/time` and the time command will output the time it took the script to run. This is more portable than the using something `bash` specific.

Answer (score 6):

While using `SECONDS` and `time` will give you relative values. If you'd like to have absolute values for Auditing and Reporting Purposes as to when the script ran and when it completed, you might want to try something like this before and after your commands 
    `date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N'` . This could also give you a better granularity as it can capture sub-second differences as you have commands like `ping` which normally execute within a second.

Answer (score 1):

Nest your script.
To send an email there are a number of options. I personally favour msmtp for this, you can define the headers yourself "here" style (inline) or use a separate file and cat them together. There are all sorts of alternatives to this involving perl, python etc.

```
Reply-To: someone@somehost
Sender: someone <someone@somehost>
To: somebody@somewhere.else
Subject: some subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
```

The trailing blank line is important.
cat your assembled message into msmtp thusly :

```
cat assembled.eml | msmtp somebody@somewhere.else
```

A pessimist would loop until success a reasonable number of times.

The payload could also be html, and could be php generated.

A very ugly alternative for "batchy" operation overnight say is to create a cronjob and the output is emailed in lieu of stdout/stderr.